# EKS nodes scaling to 0

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a question about EKS scaling nodes to 0. If there are no nodes in the cluster(which means auto scaling group set nodes to 0) how are different services running in EKS . like kube-proxy etc?

Shouldn't these services need a node in order to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EKS node scaling is only for worker nodes.

AWS manages control plane in a AWS managed account. You don't see those nodes in your account.

> The Amazon EKS control plane consists of control plane nodes that run the Kubernetes software, such as etcd and the Kubernetes API server. The control plane runs in an account managed by AWS, and the Kubernetes API is exposed via the Amazon EKS endpoint associated with your cluster. Each Amazon EKS cluster control plane is single-tenant and unique, and runs on its own set of Amazon EC2 instances.
>
> All of the data stored by the etcd nodes and associated Amazon EBS
> volumes is encrypted using AWS KMS. The cluster control plane is
> provisioned across multiple Availability Zones and fronted by an
> Elastic Load Balancing Network Load Balancer. Amazon EKS also
> provisions elastic network interfaces in your VPC subnets to provide
> connectivity from the control plane instances to the nodes (for
> example, to support kubectl exec logs proxy data flows).

Check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/clusters.html#:%7E:text=The%20Amazon%20EKS%20control%20plane%20consists,own%20set%20of%20Amazon%20EC2%20instances.)